# How to replace a list of strings by another list

Tags: linux, sed, text-editing

I have a file which has (many) strings I'd like to replace, so I thought about using a simple command like:

```
sed 's/string1/string2/g' file1 > out
```

However, there are too many strings for that to be repeated manually. So I made a list of all the strings to be replaced, each in a line, and named it file A. Then I made a list of all the replacement strings, and named it file B.

Is there a way to do something like:

```
sed 's/line i of file A/line i of file B/g' file1 > out
```

for each line of file A?

Answer (score 4):

It would be easier to create a file with both the input and replacement strings on the same line (assuming that neither input nor replacement strings contain spaces). Then you can do so something simple like:

```
while read n k; do sed -i "s/$n/$k/g" file1; done < fileA
```

---

EDIT:

After seeing Nykakin's answer, I realized you can do the same thing with the two files you have combining his suggestion with mine:

```
paste fileA fileB | while read n k; do sed -i "s/$n/$k/g" file1; done
```

Comment: +1, this answer is simpler than mine and doesn't require subshell.

Comment: NIce, this worked! just in my case I needed to use double quotes (`"s/$n/$k/g"` instead of `'s/$n/$k/g'`)  
Also, if it helps anybody I'd name the files like this:    
fileA --> replace_what  
fileB --> replace_with  
file1 --> file_to_process  
^^

Answer (score 1):

This is basically your first idea, but with the substitution commands put into a file, so they’re more manageable:

```
tmpfile=/tmp/Asasuser.$$
exec 3< fileA
exec 4< fileB
while read –r astring <&3
do
        read –r bstring <&4
        echo "s/$astring/$bstring/" >> "$tmpfile"
done
exec 3<&- 4<&-
sed –f "$tmpfile" file1 > out
rm –f "$tmpfile"
```

This assumes that `fileA` and `fileB` have the same number of lines (and that that number is greater than zero) and that neither of them has any unescaped `/` characters.

Answer (score 1):

We can just generate command that we need. Let's say that files with lists are called lista and listb. Then we can use:

```
$ for i in $(paste lista listb -d/); do echo -n "-e 's/$i/g' "; done
```

to generate option for sed. Now we can use it with eval. Let's say our file is called test. We use:

```
$ eval "sed" $(for i in $(paste lista listb -d/); do echo -n "-e 's/$i/g' "; done) "test"
```

Comment: You don't need the `eval` (see my answer) but +1 for paste, I hadn't thought of that.

Answer (score 0):

```
paste -d : fileA fileB | sed 's/\([^:]*\):\([^:]*\)/s%\1%\2%/' > sed.script
sed -f  sed.script SOURCE-FILE
```

`SOURCE-FILE` may be either an  individual file or multiple files. The text in fileA and fileB cannot contain either colon or percent characters, but may contain blank characters.